# Is it possible to get array of all index paths for the cells in a UITableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, nsindexpath

Is there a simple way to get array of all index paths for the cells in a UITableView?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you are the one that told the table view how many sections and rows per section you had, you can use that same data - or in fact even call the same methods on your data source to ask that question from elsewhere.